# Order list by max date of a children (using Hibernate Critéria)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to sort a list by the max date of a children class, using hibernate criteria:

**Domain:**

```
class Entity {
    List<Children> childrens;
}

class Children {
    Date date
}
```

**Something like this in SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    entity
INNER JOIN 
    children c1 ON c1.entity_id = entity.id
WHERE 
    c1.date = 
        (SELECT MAX(c2.date) FROM children c2 WHERE c2.entity_id = c1.entity_id) 
ORDER BY 
    c1.date DESC
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate something like that with HQL or the JPA Criteria API. Here is the HQL version:

```
from
    Entity e
order by
    (select max(c.date) from e.children c) desc
```

or with the Criteria API:

```
CriteriaBuiler cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Entity> q = cb.createQuery(Entity.class);
Root<Entity> r = q.from(Entity.class);
Subquery<Date> s = q.subquery(Date.class);
Join<?, ?> c = s.correlate(r).join("children");
s.select(cb.max(c.get("date")));
q.orderBy(cb.desc(s));
List<Entity> list = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```